# Php If else isn't working

Tags: php, mysql

I have an if else statement, but its not working correctly. When I add it in, it only echos the first statement even if the database info doesn't match the `=` in the if statement, what did I do wrong?

```
$gameum = $db->fetch("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE `id` = '$id'");

$status = $gameum['status'];
$gameid = $gameum['gameid'];
$search = $gameum['seraching_for'];

if($gameum['status'] = '0' ) {
$data ='<h1> Who do you want to battle against? </h1><br />
        <form action=""  method="post" id="form-pb" name="pb"   target="_self" >
        USERNAME:<input name="name" type="text" size="40" maxlength="40" />

        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search"/>
        </form>
        <a class="goback" href="#">Cancel</a>';
}  else { 
    $data = '<h1> Searching </h1> <br /> Searching for '.$search.'';
}
```

Screenshot of the database row:

[image]

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, `==` for comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$gameum['status'] = '0' // assigns the value '0' to $gamenum['status']

($gameum['status'] == '0')  // compares the two values
```

Answer (score 2):

Your **`if`** statement should be

```
if($gameum['status'] == '0' ) {
```

and if you are looking for `strict` check , i suggest you do

```
if($gameum['status'] === '0' ) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are Assigning`$gameum['status']` to `0`  , if is a conditional statement
add double equal `==` to if  condition, change

```
 if($gameum['status'] = '0' ) {
```

with

```
 if($gameum['status'] == '0' ) {
```

Single equal `=`   Assigns the value.

Double equal `==`  Compare value, == does not care about the data types when comparing.

Triple equal `===` The data types are checked to make sure the two `vars/objects/whatever` are using the same type.

Answer (score 0):

**Change**

```
if($gameum['status'] = '0' )
```

**with**

```
if($gameum['status'] == '0' )
```

`=` for `assigning` value.

`==` `compares` the values of variables for equality

`===` checks if the two variables are of the `same type` and have the `same value`.